# Prevent to cancel Action Mode by press back button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Action mode started by calling `getActivity().startActionMode(calback);` is automatically canceled after back button pressed. Is possible avoid this behavior? I need to do another operation after back button was pressed in some situation during action mode.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. When the ActionMode is active the back key event is consumed internally. The event is **not** propagated to either `onBackPressed()` or `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` callbacks.

Fortunately, you can use `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` which is still called.

```java
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(mActionModeIsActive) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // handle your back button code here
           return true; // consumes the back key event - ActionMode is not finished
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

You might wonder what will be the behavior in case you have a submenu in the ActionMode and you close it with the back key. In this case `dispatchKeyEvent()` is not called so you can safely use the code.

The above code works also with ActionBarSherlock. The only problem I found is on Android 3.1 device when the native ActionMode is used, in this case the `dispatchKeyEvent()` is not called. Use ActionBarSherlock's ActionMode to solve it.

Comment: Could you be a little bit clearer on what you mean with "Use ActionBarSherlock's ActionMode to solve it."?

Comment: On an Android 3.1 device `dispatchKeyEvent()` is not called if you do not use ActionBarSherlock. If you use it, it is called (ActionBarSherlock uses custom implementation of ActionBar for Android 3.x).

Comment: This answer not working for me. Any ideas about my question here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683145/prevent-back-button-whilst-actionmode-is-active

Answer (score 0):

Suggested solutions did not work for me. So I decide to create `back` event manually. I needed this event in my fragment so I created `BaseFragment` that all my fragments will extend.

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    private ActionModeState actionModeState = ActionModeState.ITEM_NOT_CLICKED;

    protected enum ActionModeState {
        ITEM_NOT_CLICKED, ITEM_CLICKED
    }

    protected void onActionItemClicked() {
        actionModeState = ActionModeState.ITEM_CLICKED;
    }

    protected void onDestroyActionMode() {
        if (actionModeState == ActionModeState.ITEM_NOT_CLICKED) {
            onActionModeBackPressed();
        } else {
            // reset state
            actionModeState = ActionModeState.ITEM_NOT_CLICKED;
        }
    }

    protected void onActionModeBackPressed() { }

}
```

Main fragment

```
public class YourMainFragment extends BaseMapFragment {

    @Override
    public void onActionModeBackPressed() {
        // you code for action mode back button
    }


    private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            YourMainFragment.this.onActionItemClicked();
            ....
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            YourMainFragment.this.onDestroyActionMode();
            ...
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Window.Callback and intercept event before it is passed to AppCompatDelegateImplBase.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        //default delegate
        final Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        mWindowCallbackDelegate = new WindowCallbackDelegate(window.getCallback(), this);
        window.setCallback(mWindowCallbackDelegate);
        return true;
    }
```

In your own delegate :

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    return myWindowDelegate.dispatchKeyEvent(event) || mOriginalWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

When you destroy action mode, restore reference to previous delegate

```
 @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        Window.Callback originalWindowCallback = mWindowCallbackDelegate.getOriginalWindowCallback();
        if (originalWindowCallback != null) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setCallback(originalWindowCallback);
        }}
```

You own delegate signature:

`public class WindowCallbackDelegate implements Window.Callback {...}`