# How to disable actionbar back button in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-actionmode

I use ActionMode to edit some content, those three buttons on the right do everything needed, and the back/home/up button on the left becomes redundant.

[image: Screenshot, see that button on the left]

Here's the ActionMode

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.editormenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_cancel:
                selectedView.onCancelEditing();
                selectedView.enableEditMode(selectedView,false);
                mode.finish(); 
                return true;
            case R.id.action_remove:
                selectedView.enableEditMode(selectedView,false);
                relContainer.removeView(selectedView);
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_done:
                selectedView.enableEditMode(selectedView,false);
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
};
```

I tried to use that back/home/up button as "cancel" button but it seems that it's id is not android.R.id.home nor R.id.home

so question is: How do I remove/disable this button, OR How do I make use of it?

Comment: Have a look on this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725729/prevent-to-cancel-action-mode-by-press-back-button

Comment: Thanks for the info, the link you gave is about physical back key. What I'm trying to achieve is to disable that arrow on the top left (take a look at the screenshot)

Comment: Priyanka Minhas you were right, could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `dispatchKeyEvent` method and perform action on it:
Have a look on the following example:

```
@Override 
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if(mActionModeIsActive) { 
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
           // handle your back button code here 
           return true; // consumes the back key event - ActionMode is not finished 
        } 
    } 
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

For further info:

[Prevent to cancel Action Mode by press back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725729/prevent-to-cancel-action-mode-by-press-back-button)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is what worked for me:

[remove back/home button from action mode on long press in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138881/remove-back-home-button-from-action-mode-on-long-press-in-android)

I added these lines to my styles.xml

```
 <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@color/colorAccent</item>
 <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode</item>
 <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

I am using `@color/colorAccent` as the background colour for the ActionBar in ActionMode.