# remove back/home button from action mode on long press in android

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode, actionmode

I have implemented contextual action mode on long press inside `recycler view`. For that i have called `ActionModeCallback` from creating action mode .

While creating action mode , back arrow is showing by default . 
Check below :

[image]

On click back arrow , action mode will close.

Now i want to `hide` or `remove` that default back button which is coming along with `action mode` in android .

Note : Already tried `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false).` but it's not working . Kindly help.

Edited :

Thanks Issues been resolved : 
After adding in style.xml

```
<item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode</item>
```

Comment: I think you should paste your solution in answer section so it could be accepted and useful counter would be increased.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to completely remove it:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);      
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
}
```

**Update**

or try to using a custom theme

```
<style name="yourTheme" parent="theThemeYouUse">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/yourBack</item>
</style>
```

and in the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="yourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/yourTheme"
  ...
/>
```

Comment: just want to remove back button from contextual action mode, not from previous action bar.

Comment: have you try to use a custom theme?

Comment: i m implementing action mode in fragment class not in activity. Also try above style in parent activity style . But not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add below the item to your style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
     ...
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/NoCloseButtonActionModeStyle</item>
    </style>
<style name="NoCloseButtonActionModeStyle">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>
```