# Preventing cancel of ActionMode using the back button

Tags: java, android, back-button, android-actionmode

I have an `ActionMode` in my fragment and I want to override what the back button on does, I still want the toolbar's "done" button to exit the action mode as usual.
I already seen this post:
[Prevent to cancel Action Mode by press back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725729/prevent-to-cancel-action-mode-by-press-back-button)
This doesn't seem to be working, when I press the back button I indeed enter the `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` and the  `if` scope described in the given answer, but returning `true` doesn't do anything and the `ActionMode` is still finished.
On any other scenario the back button indeed gets overriden as mentioned above but pressing back on `ActionMode` bypasses it somehow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that back even is handled internally regardless of overriding of dispatchKeyEvent and onBackPressed methods. There is an additional onBackPressed method (returning boolean) in AppCompatDelegateImplV7 that performs a check on availability of ActionMode as a first step on an internal reference. [Here is code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java#L801).

Comment: So I should extend AppCompatDelegateImplV7 and override onBackPressed? Will try when I'll get home and update, thanks

Comment: You cannot directly extend AppCompatDelegateImplV7, because this class is visible only within its own package. You should eventually extend AppCompatDelegate abstract class and also define a custom Activity type. Take a look at AppCompatActivity implementation [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.java). It keeps its own delegate and forward to it operations execution. Don't know if it is the right direction, but I played with basic events and didn't find any easy solution.

Comment: Is there a difference in behavior depending on if you use support action mode or regular action mode?